# Anything Else Like An Iframe? I want to do Whatever we can do with Iframe

Tags: html, iframe

Really, i like to use iframe. because iframe will reduce the transferring data between server & client. We can display the static contents in out of iframe & dynamic content in iframe. But many developers are saying "iframe isn't good". I don't know whether it's correct or not. If anybody know about iframe please don't forget to answer. and i need to know any other ideas such as iframe.

Comment: What about AJAX calls?

Comment: *“Really, i like to use iframe. because iframe will reduce the transferring data between server & client.”* You’re doing it wrong. Just don’t use an `<iframe>` at all. Make proper, whole pages.

Answer (score 1):

Just use ajax (XMLHttpRequest). You can send/receive requests from the client and server without the use and problems that come with iframes.

Answer (score -2):

Probably I would recommend [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).